# Spring Boot application doesn't stop at any breakpoint in debug

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

I have simple Maven Spring Boot application: @SpringBootApplication main class and @RequestMapping controller.
There's a `System.out.println("stop");` statement in the controller.

I run the application in debug with mvnDebug in Windows with IntelliJ IDEA 2020:

- command to run app: `mvnDebug spring-boot:run`
- MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS in ${MAVEN_HOME}\bin\mvnDebug.cmd: `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -DforkMode=never -Dmaven.failsafe.debug`

So I started the app, see a prompt: `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005`

Then I ran 'remote' run configuration. I can see how my app has started. Then I invoked controller's endpoint. I can see `stop` string in the log.

Then I put a breakpoint at string `System.out.println("stop");`. Invoked again controller's method. And I can see again `stop` string in the log instead of stopping at breakpoint.

What I should do to make my IDEA stop at breakpoint in debug?

I suppose that issue is about forking JVM but can't resolve it.

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: No, because it's not Maven application in that tutorial.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: As I remember no, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IntelliJ is not connected to the running application. Have you tried starting the application in debug mode from IntelliJ itself?